# How to read data file having column name in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have the following data

```
  Individual     Heart rate     Weight    Hours of exercise per week
       1           72            134             3.2
       2           81            201             3.5
       3           60            156             7.1
       4           82            148             2.4
       5           75            170             1.2
```

I have to compute standard deviation and make scatter plot between these variables.

If i don't write the column name in a .txt file , then i  can compute the computation by using the command   `load('filename')` .

But i have to consider the column name. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest the [`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) function.

```
A = importdata('your_file.dat');
data = A.data;
size(data) % 5x4 double
header = A.textdata;
```

It directly provides the data and could also properly split the header if it was using a delimiter such as comma or tab.

Since Matlab Version 2013b there is also a new [`table`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/table.html) datatype around which might be interesting: [`readtable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html). However, I haven't tried that myself yet.

And as a third suggestion, the data import wizard (when just double clicking on a data file or `uiimport`) allows some manual fine tuning and can also generate a function or script to automate the import of your specific file format (In some newer Matlab versions).

Comment: This is awesome. I am a beginner in MATLAB.

Answer (score -4):

I think MATLAB is not like R that has data frame.

All is Matrix in MATLAB.

So maybe you can load the column name in another matrix,
and use it together with you data matrix.

Comment: Could you please explain how can i use the matrices (data matrix and the matrix that contains column name) together ? It would be very kind if you give an example .

Comment: Matlab does have data structures that can handle headers such as the (new) native Table structure as well as datasets in the stats toolbox etc. Also Cell matrices can handle this to a degree as well or else structs.